# div overflow it parent div and unsolved margins

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with the info div overflowing it parent container but not it content ,some other component are also overflowing but it's not a problem and a margins problem some are just there and the others won't appear at all this is happening in width under 375px
plus if any one has an idea why the font awesome icon appears as a square i couldn't find a solution

update

the overflow problem has been solved but i still have a problem with the extra margin of the html on the right and the lack of for the container

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="images/image-product-desktop.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
        <span class="type">Perfume</span>
        <h1 class="title">Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfume</h1>
        <p>A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Oliver Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
        <div class="prices">
            <span class="newprice">$149.99</span>
            <span class="oldprice">$169.99</span>
        </div>
        <button><i class="fa-regular fa-cart-shopping"></i> Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

`

`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
}
html{
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.container{
    max-width: 37rem;
    max-height: 45rem;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}
img{
    max-width: 18.5rem;
    max-height: 45rem;
    border-top-left-radius: .5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
}

.title{
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    color: black;
    margin: .8rem auto 1rem;
}
.info{
    padding: 1.9rem;  
}
p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
}
.prices{
    margin: 1.5rem auto 1.3rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.newprice{
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #658354;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.oldprice{
    text-decoration:line-through;
    font-size: .7rem;
    margin: 1rem;
}
button{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #658354;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: .8rem;
    border: none;
    padding: .7rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:active{
    background-color: #2f4125;
}
@media(max-width : 375px){
    *{
        margin: 1rem;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        border-radius: .5rem;
    }
    .container{
        display: block;
    }
    .info{
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can add in css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 375px) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `max-height: 45rem;` property from container class

Comment: thanks it solved the overflow problem

Comment: any idea about the margin situation

Comment: `.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }` add this in the media query container class. also add a padding in top container class

Answer (score 0):

for any one who has the margin problem as i do here i solved it by eliminating the  body height and width to auto in the 375 max-width media